# Чем отличаются методы от конструкторов в java?

Tags: java, методы, конструктор

Чем отличаются методы от конструкторов в java?
Для чего нужно то и другое?

Comment: Привидите пример того, после чего у вас возник вопрос.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19061599/2881286

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструктор предназначен для создания экземпляра класса (объекта) при помощи ключевого слова `new` и могут иметь имена только совпадающие с именем класса.

Методы выполняют операции данными как для существующих объектов, так и без создания объекта вовсе (статические методы).

Из конструкторов нельзя ничего возвращать, т.к. по сути они уже возвращают объект класса. Методы должны возвращать хотя бы `void`.

Answer (score 7):

Главное отличие между конструкторами и методами в том, что конструкторы инициализируют объекты, создаваемые с помощью оператора `new`, в то время как методы выполняют операции с уже существующими объектами.

Конструкторы не могут быть вызваны напрямую; они вызываются когда объект создается с помощью ключевого слова `new`. Методы же, могут быть вызваны напрямую у объекта, который уже был создан.

Определение конструкторов и методов похожи. Они могут принимать параметры, иметь модификаторы (т.е. `public`), а так же имеют тело которое будет выполняться.

Конструкторы могут иметь только имя совпадающее с именем класса. Из них нельзя ничего возвращать, даже `void`, так как на самом деле они уже возвращают новый объект.

Методы должны что-то возвращать, хотя бы `void`.

<sub>перевод [ответа @rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061630/2881286)</sub>

Comment: `Методы же, могут быть вызваны напрямую у объекта, который уже был создан.` это немного не точно, т.к. еще есть статические методы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, это на самом деле совсем точно :-) методы могут быть вызваны напрямую у объекта? - могут. :-)

Comment: формально да, возможность их позвать - есть =)

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор вызывается при создании объекта.метод вы можете вызвать после,к создоному объекту.